# How do I set the position of a Cinnamon desklet?

Tags: customization, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I'm using Cinnamon 1.8 and tried out it's native desklets.
But neither could I figure out myself nor find any documentation on how a desklet's position is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just drag it :). left click on desklet and drag.
cinnamon desklet's is little buggy on ubuntu now